# MS Access Apply Filter From Another Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have this code from another website but it's not working.
I want to filter the split view form from another form.

```
 Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

   '//Check that other form is loaded - if not, then open it
    If Not fIsLoaded("frmMain") Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmMain")
    End If
    '//Set filter to listbox criterion
    Forms("frmMain").Filter = "[Priorities] = " & Chr(34) & Me.Priorities & Chr(34)
    Forms("frmMain").FilterOn = True

End Sub

Function fIsLoaded(ByVal strFormname As String) As Boolean

    'Returns False if form is not open or True if Open
    If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, strFormname) <> 0 Then

        If Forms(strFormname).CurrentView <> 0 Then
            fIsLoaded = True
        End If

    End If
End Function
```

I received this error
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is the form wasn't ready to take a filter yet, and that's why the error occurred. `DoCmd.OpenForm` takes a `Where` argument to set the filter when opening to prevent this from occuring.

```
 Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

   '//Check that other form is loaded - if not, then open it with the filter
    If Not fIsLoaded("frmMain") Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmMain",,,"[Priorities] = " & Chr(34) & Me.Priorities & Chr(34))
    Else
    '//Set filter to listbox criterion
    Forms("frmMain").Filter = "[Priorities] = " & Chr(34) & Me.Priorities & Chr(34)
    Forms("frmMain").FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Check if this works. If not, your filter might not be valid for that form.

Comment: Hi this macro is already filtering the query but is it showing all the data that has priority. [MasterQuery]![Priorities]=[Priorities]

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different question. If you have problems applying multiple filters to a single form, you're free to ask it.

Comment: Yup i want to filter the data if possible by priority,country,city

Comment: Well, as said, that's a different question. Don't ask it in the comments, ask a new question, and provide the necessary information for the community to answer it.